# Animation of tabpages in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, animation, tabcontrol

Is it possible to do animation of tabpages as they switch in VB.NET?

So, when one person switches tabpages the current one might slide to reveal the next.

Is this possible to do, or is it complicated?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course it is possible. The difficulty comes to the animation and what each tab contains. A simple slide is quite simple, using a timer. Bear in mind, in order to have a smooth slide the timer tick must be the same as your screen frequency eg for 60Hz a 16msec is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply put all the controls that you have on a tabpage on a panel.  And slide the panel with a 15 msec timer:

```
Dim tabPageOffset As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    tabPageOffset -= 10          `` Tweak to change speed
    If tabPageOffset <= 0 Then
        tabPageOffset = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls(0).Left = tabPageOffset
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As TabControlCancelEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.Selecting
    tabPageOffset = e.TabPage.ClientSize.Width
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```